# How to add a file where a file has moved in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I moved a file from a.txt to b.txt using `hg mv`

Then I created a new file called a.txt

I did it this way because I want to preserve the history of a.txt in b.txt, and a.txt is logically a new file so I don't want it to have any history.

And I want to do all of this in a single changeset / commit.

Can mercurial handle this?

When I try, my client isn't clean after committing for some reason, and it seems to think the file is still actually being deleted where it was moved from in the changeset. Or something.

Answer (score 1):

it seems not possible with current control versions, most (all?) of them considering a *moved* file as if it was *deleted* and *added* but with the enhancement of keeping track of its history

therefore in the very same commit you cannot move it and at the same time start a new one with a name clash, or else it wouldn't account as "deleted" which is a requirement for it to be "moved"

OTOH, think about how it would look like the `diff` of such commit?

Comment: true, given version control thinks of move as copy+delete, it makes sense why this doesnt work. i think that's unfortunate. they could have made moves a first class operation. they could also make a first class "replace" operation that is delete+add (modify but with history cleared). i think showing a diff would still be possible. it would show the same diff it would show if you asked for a diff across two commits where you do the delete in one and the add in another.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to copy the original file instead of move it using `hg cp`. The only downside is that it preserves the history of a.txt and doesn't show it as having moved. However if preserving the history of b.txt is your primary goal, this may be good enough.